# Ubuntu 22.04 GRUB not detecting keyboard when wireless mouse dongle plugged in

Tags: grub2, usb, hardware

When I have my wireless mouse dongle plugged in (Razor Deathadder v2 pro) grub doesn't detect my WIRED USB keyboard. The only way I can get it to work is by unplugging my dongle, and rebooting. When the dongle isn't in, the keyboard works just fine in grub.

The strange issue is that this doesn't ALWAYS happen. It works fine every now and then, but the majority of the time it doesn't work.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Fresh install of 22.04.

Comment: Can you plugin both devices and run `lsusb`?

Comment: Both devices are detected when booting into Ubuntu. Grub is my main issue. I dual boot so it gets annoying when trying to switch and the kb doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem that I resolved by changing a bios setting.  One of the fast boot bios settings on my motherboard prevented the system from scanning the USB devices on power up.  That prevented the o/s from seeing the USB attached dongle.  I disable the fast boot option and that resolved my issue.

Comment: I'll give that a try and see what happens.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. I disabled fast boot and still run into the issue.

Comment: This was it for me, even though the bios had usb full usb support enabled under fast boot settings

Answer (score 0):

I have literally the same problem with Razer Deathadder V2 Hyperspeed.
When USB dongle is plugged in I cannot use laptop keyboard. On first key press the countdown disappears and I cannot select anything and I must reset the laptop. Even pressing enter as the first key does not boot Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
It does not occur every time, but like 90% of boots.

Fast boot does not have any impact on the problem - it still persists.

Comment: I found that this issue is happening when the dongle is plugged into anything that is considered a USB HUB. I removed my dongle from my hub and plugged it directly into my motherboard and I no longer have issues.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But I'm connecting the dongle to the laptop so that means that laptop manufacturer did some hack and it is not a direct connect to the motherboard.